# WebScraping User Reviews using Scrapy Not Going to 'Next' page

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, selenium-chromedriver

I was able to scrape the first page of rotten tomatoes 'all audience' reviews of this movie: https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/ghostbusters/reviews?type=user.

My problem now is that unlike the "all critic" reviews to load more reviews, in 'all audience' you click "Next" rather than clicking "next page" which adds to the URL page=2 for example. Now that I can't do that I need to figure out how to click 'Next' and get the new link.

I'm wondering if I need to use selenium and make a web driver to complete this task.

I'm new to using the developer tools and having trouble with finding the correct name to reference the "next" button. Below is my code that successfully pulls the first page (but not the following consecutive pages desired) and a screenshot of the developer end of the website for reference. Any insight or suggestions would be greatly appreciated:

```
import scrapy

class ReviewsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'reviews'
    allowed_domains = ['rottentomatoes.com']

    start_urls = ['https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/ghostbusters/reviews/?type=user']

    def parse(self, response):

        #Extracting the content using css selectors
        reviews = response.css('.audience-reviews__review::text').extract()

        #Give the extracted content row wise
        for item in zip(reviews):
            #create a dictionary to store the scraped info
            scraped_info = {
                'review' : item[0],
            }

            #yield or give the scraped info to scrapy
            yield scraped_info

        next_page_url = response.xpath('//li[//*[@id="content"]/div/div/nav[3]/button[2]/span]/a/@href').extract_first()
        if next_page_url:
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page_url, callback=self.parse)
```

[Developer Tool End Screenshot #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdDE6.png)
[Developer Tool End Screenshot #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhwSs.png)

Answer (score 0):

The main thing here is a request which we made after push the "Next button". We should update it with SiteID, endCursor, and startCursor (also we may update direction).

[image]

All necessary parameters we may find in the source code of the page. Under "root.RottenTomatoes.context.movieReview"
[image]

We may grab code with regex and make a python dictionary to easily get all parameters.

```
regex = r'root\.RottenTomatoes\.context\.movieReview = (.*?);'
movie_review_data = re.findall(regex, tomatoes_scripts)[0]
movie_review_data_dict = json.loads(movie_review_data)
```

Then we grab SiteID, endCursor, and endCursor

```
movie_id = movie_review_data_dict.get('movieId')
next_page = movie_review_data_dict.get('pageInfo').get('hasNextPage')
end_cursor = movie_review_data_dict.get('pageInfo').get('endCursor')
```

We are able to grab the first comments from the page and make the next request with a special URL that we build using our parameters. The response is a JSON object which we make as a Python dictionary (and which contains our updated parameters for the next page).

[image]

After that, we loop our method and grab all necessary fields from the dictionary. I've provided full code but be advised it works but it's a draft, of course, we must use the best Scrapy practice like Items, ItemLoaders, make a separate file for generate_review_url function, etc.. The code was written on the fly and show the main idea and just works

```
import scrapy
import re
import json


def generate_review_url(movie_id,
                        end_cursor,
                        start_cursor=''):
    return f'https://www.rottentomatoes.com/napi/movie/{movie_id}'\
        f'/reviews/user?direction=next&'\
        f'endCursor={end_cursor}&startCursor={start_cursor}'


class ReviewsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'reviews'
    allowed_domains = ['rottentomatoes.com']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/ghostbusters/reviews?type=user'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        tomatoes_scripts = response.xpath(
            '//script[contains(text(), "function (root)")]/text()'
        ).get()

        regex = r'root\.RottenTomatoes\.context\.movieReview = (.*?);'
        movie_review_data = re.findall(regex, tomatoes_scripts)[0]
        movie_review_data_dict = json.loads(movie_review_data)
        movie_id = movie_review_data_dict.get('movieId')
        next_page = movie_review_data_dict.get('pageInfo').get('hasNextPage')
        end_cursor = movie_review_data_dict.get('pageInfo').get('endCursor')

        reviews = response.xpath('//ul[@class="audience-reviews"]/li')
        for review in reviews:
            yield {
                'review': review.xpath(
                    './/p[contains(@class, "audience-reviews__review")]/text()'
                ).get()
            }

        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=generate_review_url(movie_id, end_cursor),
                callback=self.parse_special_response,
                meta={'movie_id': movie_id}
            )

    def parse_special_response(self, response):
        response_dict = json.loads(response.body)

        reviews = response_dict.get('reviews')
        for review in reviews:
            yield {
                'review': review.get('review')
            }

        movie_id = response.meta.get('movie_id')
        next_page = response_dict.get('pageInfo').get('hasNextPage')
        end_cursor = response_dict.get('pageInfo').get('endCursor')
        start_cursor = response_dict.get('pageInfo').get('startCursor')

        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=generate_review_url(movie_id, end_cursor, start_cursor),
                callback=self.parse_special_response,
                meta={'movie_id': movie_id}
            )
```

The solution with regEx looks a bit "dirty" for me also there isn't any exception control etc. Welcome to improve =)

Looks like there are 250k+ reviews from users in users reviews. I stopped the script when I collected 11k reviews. I've tested this movie https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/pg_psycho_goreman/reviews?type=user as well and collected 46 reviews which all relevant =)

Comment: soldy you are a true angel